# List what's inside a remote git repository

Tags: linux, git, github

I know there is `git branch -a` that lists the branches in the repository but how do I see the files inside this branch when the repository is remote (can't access it from the github website).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use `git ls-files`.

Answer (score 1):

Short of using the GitHub API or another hack, it's not really possible to do this without pulling down the repository first. However, you can [if you do pull from the remote](http://git-scm.com/book/ch2-5.html).

In order to fetch all branches from remote, do `git fetch --all`. Then you can view all your branches via `git branch` and checkout to them via `git checkout -b [branch]`. Then you can simply view the files as you please from your remote using standard command line using `ls`, `cd`, `cat`, etc. If you're really rebelious you can try [Midnight Commander](https://www.midnight-commander.org/).

I recognise it might be slow pulling down large repositories over limited bandwidth (try pulling it through a VPS you SSH into?), but unfortunately there isn't much choice.